# Javascript combine arrays or strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following dynamically generated strings:

```
var stringA = ["a1", "a2", "a3" ... 'a400' ... 'a600']; // length 600
var stringB = ["b1", "b2", "b3" ... 'b400']; // length 400
```

How can I get an Array or string of both combined like this:

```
var myString = ["a1b1", "a2b2", "a3b3" ... "a400b400", "a401" ... "a600"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var result = [], len = Math.max(stringA.length, stringB.length);
for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push((stringA[i] || "") + (stringB[i] || ""));
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/kcMBn/), the `|| ""` is to prevent getting `undefined` as a string on the for the array that's shorter. The `Math.max()` call is to allow *either* `A` or `B` to be longer, it'll iterate to the end of either, just as `A` is longer in the question.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I forgot that I *should* use `Math.max()` to avoid iterating past a smaller array. So +1 to you Nick!

Comment: Thanx Nick! You've helped me out again!

Comment: This will result in entries in the destination array at indexes where there aren't entries in either source array (if there are any such entries).

Comment: @TJCrowder - If you look at the question, that's what the OP as asking for originally, a went to 600, b went to 400 :)

Comment: Just sayin', if we're going to handle empty slots, let's handle empty slots. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built into the `Array` object that will do it for you, you'll have to do the loop. The loop is trivial, though:

```
var index, length;
var result = [];
// assertion: arrayA.length === arrayB.length
result.length = arrayA.length; // Helps performance in some implemenations, harmless in others
for (index = 0, length = arrayA.length; index < length; ++index) {
     result[index] = arrayA[index] + arrayB[index];
}
```

(I've renamed `stringA` -> `arrayA` and `stringB` -> `arrayB` to avoid confusion.)

If the arrays are different lengths **or** some of the entries in the arrays are undefined (which is totally possible, JavaScript arrays are sparse), you'll want to handle that in the loop, e.g.:

```
var index, length, Apresent, Bpresent;
var result = [];
result.length = Math.max(arrayA.length, arrayB.length); // Helps performance in some implementations, harmless in others
for (index = 0, length = result.length; index < length; ++index) {
     Apresent = arrayA.hasOwnProperty(index);
     Bpresent = arrayB.hasOwnProperty(index);
     if (Apresent && Bpresent) {
         result[index] = arrayA[index] + arrayB[index];
     }
     else if (Apresent) {
         result[index] = arrayA[index];
     }
     else if (Bpresent) {
         result[index] = arrayB[index];
     }
}
```

If the arrays are sparse and they both happen to be sparse at the same index, the resulting array will also be sparse.

Comment: This will also result in a lot of `undefined` when the array lengths do differ, as they do in the question :)

Comment: @Nick: Thanks. It wasn't at all clear from the question originally that the arrays might be different lengths (he showed them as the same length), but I see what you mean in his example result (subtle, that). I saw your other comment and was updating as you commented here. :-) I see someone's fixed the question for him.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to retain the the items in the original 2 arrays then the code below works really well.  It does not have a predetermined limit to the number of iterations in the for loop which means that the `stringA` and `StringB` array could continue to grow in size while this code is running.

```
var myString = [];
for(var answer; answer = (stringA.shift() || "") + (stringB.shift() || "");) {
    myString.push(answer);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myString = [];

for (var i=0;i<stringA.length;i++){
     myString[i] = stringA[i] + stringB[i];
}
```

Comment: This won't work, you'll get `"undefined"` in many places when the array lengths differ, as in the question.